# Alt + Shift to change language no longer working after upgrade to Windows 10

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-10

Just updated to Windows 10. The expected change language shortcut stopped working.

In the settings it shows that "Alt + Shift" is supposed to work, just like before the upgrade, but it does not. The tool tip window that is shown when I float over the language bar says that the shortcut is "Windows key + Space", which works, but I prefer "Alt + Shift" like it used to be.

How can I make it use "Alt + Shift" again?

Comment: I've re-read this a couple of times... What is the question? Are you wanting to remap the shortcut to what it used to be?

Comment: The shortcut doesn't work.

Comment: But you said that Windows key + space does work... Does that not work as well?

Comment: In the settings it shows that "alt + shift" supposed to work; but it doesn't. "win key + space" does work - can't change the shortcut

Comment: So back to my first question... WinKey + space works (as intended, it looks like), but you want it to be changed to Alt + shift? I'm having a hard time finding out what you are wanting to do.

Comment: Before upgrading, the shortcut was "alt + shift", now "alt + shift" stopped working, in the settings I still see that this shortcut is selected as the working one. "win key + space" works, but I want it to be "alt + shift"

Comment: There is a problem with lenevo and windows 10 and the numlock key.
actually I don't why but the problem is solved when I opened the numlock and the alt button worked!
check this link for more info
http://www.worldstart.com/alt-keys-not-working-in-windows-10/

Answer (score 30):

Go to ***Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings***, in a section called ***Switching input methods*** click on ***Change language bar hotkeys***, continue with ***Advanced key settings*** tab, then click on button ***Change Key Sequence...*** and then choose from a list called ***Switch Keyboard Layout*** your desired ***LEFT ALT + SHIFT*** hotkey.

Comment: as I said this option already selected

Comment: In a language settings, there should be one _Windows display language_, which has two _keyboard layouts_ added, for example US and DE. Go again to in _Change Key Sequence..._ menu a make sure you've chosen the option _Not Assigned_ in a column _Switch Input Language_ and your _Left Alt + Shift_ in the _Switch Keyboard Layout_ column. Then it should work. At least it works for me.

Comment: I could not make it work on my Lenovo S21e-20 notebook. The only setting that allows me to iterate through keyboards (languages) is when I have the "Use the desktop language bar when it's available" unchecked and the following language bar hotkeys set: Switch Input Language: Ctrl + Shift; Switch Keyboard Layout: Left Alt + Shift. Actually, the Left Alt + Shift does not seem to do anything, but at least, I can switch languages using a hotkey combination (not the one I normally used, but it's better than nothing).

Comment: The weird thing is that it works fine on all other systems I upgraded. Just Lenovo has this issue.

Comment: There is a problem with lenevo and windows 10 and the numlock key.
actually I don't why but the problem is solved when I opened the numlock and the alt button worked!
check this link for more info
http://www.worldstart.com/alt-keys-not-working-in-windows-10/

Comment: Just follow sequence that is in the answer, then pay attention there is **two combinations**: one for _"Input language"_ and other for _"Keyboard layout"_. What you probably need is _"Keyboard layout"_

Comment: @RCB have you managed to fix the issue?

Comment: this Language (Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language) has already been removed

Comment: I don´t have enough privileges to write an answer. Here´s how to do it in Windows 10: Go to Settings -> Devices -> Typing (Left Panel) -> Advanced Keyboard Settings (Scroll down) -> Language bar options (Below Switching input methods) -> Advanced Key Settings -> Change Key Sequence -> Under Switch Keyboard Layout, select "Left Alt + Shift"

Comment: I am having the same problem did you fix it?

Answer (score 11):

The question is quite old. However, there is a common misunderstanding of the *language* concept of Windows 10 in the question. The concept also was not captured by any of the answers.

## Meaning of the shortcuts

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> changes the *language*, if I have defined different languages as described below.

<kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> changes the *keyboard layout* within the currecntly selected language, if I have defined different keyboards as described below.

## Background

In Windows 10, there is a difference between *language* and *keyboard layout*.

In the language config window, one can choose the prefered language (see screenshot below; sorry for the German system language). E.g. the MS Word spelling correction is automatically adapted to the current language.

[image]

For each language, the user may define one or more keyboard layouts. First, the user clicks onto the language (next picture) and, then, she can choose "Optionen" ("Options" in English GUI?).

[image]

In the language options windows, the user can add different keyboard layouts. Swichting a keyboard layout does not impact app behaviour with respect to its language settings.

[image]

For each language one can define an individual set of keyboard layouts.

## Which language and keyboard layout are selected?

Below are two screenshots of my Windows 10 taskbar. The top row in each picture indicates the system language (German ("DEU") in my case). The bottom row indicates the keyboard layout (German in the first and US-English in the second picture).

[image]

[image]

If there is only one row, it indicates the system language with default keyboard. Please correct me, if I am wrong with this.

Comment: this is the correct answer, I wonder why so few upvotes

Comment: The question really was about languages as far as I can tell, though. Ever since windows added language options, hitting alt-shift with multiple languages installed (e.g. EN + JP + DE) will cycle through your languages (e.g. EN -> JP -> DE -> EN). However, sometimes Windows 10 breaks itself, and even though the alt-shift key is clearly set as the cycling hotkey, it instead pops up the little overlay that shows all your languages, while refusing to cycle to the next one at all.

Answer (score 3):

For me this worked (Late Answer, but I hope it will be helpful for future visitors):

1. `Search for Setting --> Time & Language --> Language`
2. `Spelling, typing, & keyboard settings --> Advanced keyboard settings`
3. `Language bar options`
4. `Advanced Key Settings --> Between input languages --> Change Key Sequence --> Left ALT + Shift`

You can also search for `Advanced keyboard settings` directly and make your way shorter.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when adding a 2nd keyboard layout.
I deleted the 2nd layout, installed a complete 2nd displaylangue containing the 2nd keyboard layout and the problem is solved.

Shift+tab only seems to work when switching between keyboard lay-outs in different display language on my machine. Perhaps you have the same issue.