# Change input language shortcut for all users

Tags: windows, windows-10, input-languages

How to make input language shortcut system default? I'm using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, but it not works on another accounts and logon screen (while <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> does).

**Update**: I know about <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, but I need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>.

Comment: Here's a similar reference link to https://superuser.com/questions/949712/alt-shift-to-change-language-no-longer-working-after-upgrade-to-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

The default shortcut to cycle through the available input languages is "Windows Key + Spacebar".
This will cause a GUI to pop up on the right-hand side of your screen which will show the currently selected input languages. Repeatedly pressing "Windows Key + Spacebar" will then start the cycling.